# Unable to create an efficient, basic mutation with relationships using Hasura and GraphQL

Tags: graphql, hasura

I am building an API on top of my PostgreSQL database,
using Hasura and GraphQL as the middle layer.

I run a service business, where customers can subscribe to services such as "weekly cleaning of the coffee machine" or "refilling of the mojito cabinet". A customer can only subscribe to the same service once.

We are a sales driven organization,
so we have different apps where people can add `(customer, subscription)` combination.
**We want an end point which accepts this `(customer, subscription)` combo**, and takes care of details like inserting `customer` if it does not exist.

We first tried using the following mutation against Hasura:

```
mutation InsertOrders {
  insert_orders(objects: [
    { 
      customer: {data: {name: "GE"}}, 
      subscription:  {data: {name: "Coffee Refill"}}
    }
  ]) 
  {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

This operation only succeeds if `"GE"` is not an existing customer and `"Coffee Refill"` is not an existing subscription.
We then tried using the `"on_conflict"` functionality in Hasura:

```
mutation InsertOrders {
  insert_orders(objects: [
    { 
      customer: {data: {name: "GE"}, 
        on_conflict: { constraint:customers_name_unique , update_columns:[name] }
      }, 
      subscription:  {data: {name: "Coffee Refill"},
        on_conflict: { constraint:subscriptions_name_unique , update_columns:[name] }
      }
    }
  ]) 
  {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

This kind of works, but it has several drawbacks:

1. It updates the customer (or subscription) row if the customer exists, effectively a no-op update. This also updates a potential `updated_at` column.
2. It's inefficient (see 1.). We have a tiny database (hundreds of rows), and our attempt to insert around 50 `(customer, subscription)` combos in one request timed out.

Database definition is here:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE subscription (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  customer UUID REFERENCES customer (id),
  subscription UUID REFERENCES subscription (id),
  PRIMARY KEY (customer, subscription)
)
```

Comment: To ignore the update you should leave the update_columns empty. Something like
{ on_conflict: { constraint:products_name_unique , update_columns:[] } }

Comment: @LeonardoAlves Thank you for your input. I've tried this, but I get an error `cannot proceed to insert object relation "subscription" since insert to table "subscription" affects zero rows`. 

This is mentioned under "Nested upsert caveats" [in the Hasura documentation](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/upsert.html#update-selected-columns-on-conflict)

Comment: ease of app usage should not result in bad db design ... one action in app can result in a few chained actions under the hood (update/upsert customer, create product, use results to insert order - for invoice copy user/product data, not only link them) ... order [line] should not contain direct relation to product (no consistency - product change affects earlier relations)